# Trying to make a connection between probability distributions and stochastic differential equations

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Let's say I have two SDEs $S_t$ and $R_t$:
$$dS_t = \mu (t,\omega)dt + \sigma(t,\omega)dB_t\ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ dR_t = a (t,\omega)dt + b(t,\omega)dB_t$$

where $B_t$ is the standard Brownian motion. I don't know anything more about these SDEs. Let's say I have $n$ random samples from these two processes at time = $T$.
$$X_i \sim S_T\ \text{and}\ Y_i \sim R_T$$
I now empirically estimate the Wasserstein distance between $S_T$ and $R_T$ using the $X_i$ and $Y_i$. This is to say, let's just assume that I know the (approximate) value for the Wasserstein-1 distance, defined as follows:
$$W_1(P,Q) = \sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}}\left\{ \int f(x) dP(x) - \int f(x)dQ(x)\right \}$$

Another way to write this is like this:
$$W_1(P,Q) \ge \int f(x) dP(x) - \int f(x)dQ(x)$$
$$ = \mathbb{E}_{x \sim P}[f(x)] - \mathbb{E}_{x \sim Q}[f(x)]$$

**Here is my question:
Since $P$ corresponds to $S_T$ and $Q$ corresponds to $R_T$, I want to write this last expression with expectations in terms of $S_T$ and $R_T$. Is the following conversion correct? Is there something I should do to show this more properly?**

$$\mathbb{E}_{x \sim P}[f(x)] - \mathbb{E}_{x \sim Q}[f(x)] = \mathbb{E}_{x \sim S_T}[f(x)] - \mathbb{E}_{x \sim R_T}[f(x)]$$

Then we can convert this into a common form used in stochastic calculus.

$$\mathbb{E}_{x \sim P}[f(x)] - \mathbb{E}_{x \sim Q}[f(x)] = \mathbb{E}[f(S_T)] - \mathbb{E}[f(R_T)]$$

To conclude, idea I am trying to portray is that I can estimate the difference between $S_T$ and $R_T$ by empirically estimating the Wasserstein distance using $X_i$ and $Y_i$. We can call this quantity $W_1(S_T, R_T)$, and we have the following bound.

$$W_1(S_T,R_T) \ge \mathbb{E}[f(S_T)] - \mathbb{E}[f(R_T)]$$